# Unable to read the value of hash in perl

Tags: perl, hash

In a perl code, I tried to initialize hash by having the keys & values stored in 2 separate arrays. 
To initialize arrays, data was read from a text file & then processed.

I followed the below syntax for storing keys & values into hashes:

**@hash{@key}=@values;**

**When I try to display the contents of the hash, I am able to display the contents of key alone & not the values. Why didn't the hash take in any values? How can this be resolved?**

**Text File**

```
NAME,OWE,RECEIVE
RAM,2000,1000
TEJA,1500,2200
NANDHINI,400,3000
RAGHAV,0,5000
ETHI,100,2500
KESHAV,400,400
```

**Following is my code:**

```perl
$i = 0;
open(FH, "<expenses_details.txt") or die "Couldn't open the file";
%nameo;
while ($line = <FH>)
{
    chomp($line);
    if ($i == 0)
    {
        $i++;
        next;
    }
    ($name, $owe, $receive) = split(',', $line);
    #print "Name is:$name, Owe:$owe, Receive:$receive \n"; 
    push(@names, $name); # Creating name array
    push(@owes, $owe);  #creating owe array
    push(@receives, $receive); #creating receive array
}
close FH;
print "Name array:\n";
foreach (@names)
{
    print "$_\n";
}
print "\nOWE array:\n";
foreach (@owes)
{
    print "$_\n";
}
#Initialising owe hash
@nameo{@names} = @owes;
$size = keys %nameo;
print "\nsize is $size\n";

foreach my $key (keys %nameo)
{
    print $key;
    print $nameo[$key];
    print "\n";
}
```

**OUTPUT OBTAINED:**

```
Name array:
RAM
TEJA
NANDHINI
RAGHAV
ETHI
KESHAV

OWE array:
2000
1500
400
0
100
400

size is 6
TEJA
RAM
KESHAV
ETHI
NANDHINI
RAGHAV
```

Comment: You're not accessing the %nameo hash, but the (undefined) @nameo array.  Try $nameo{$key} instead of $nameo[$key].

Comment: Put `use warnings;` and `use strict;` at the top of every Perl program you write.  They will help you with cases like this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perl is not PHP (nor Ruby). To access hash values, use curly braces, not square ones:

```
print $nameo{$key};
```

You should use [strict](http://p3rl.org/strict) and 
[warnings](http://p3rl.org/warnings). Strict would have told you you tried to access `@nameo` which wasn't declared.